# How to understand the derivatives in wave equation?

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, differentiation

I am looking at the derivation of the wave equation, but I am stuck on the math. Specifically, in the following:

[image]

How do they get the equivalence between $\frac{\partial}{\partial z} (\frac{dg}{du}) = \frac{d^2g}{du^2}\frac{\partial u}{\partial z}$

I don't get this part of the derivation.

Comment: It's best to use MathJax to typeset the equations (instead of using an image of the equations). In addition, the problem statement is incomplete because there are undefined variables and relations. It might be a good idea to include a specific reference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Context is missing to define the variables, but the question can be answered from a purely mathematical standpoint. We have a function $g(u)$ and a function $u(z,t)$. By the chain rule,
$$\frac{\partial}{\partial z} g^\prime(u(z,t)) = g^{\prime\prime}(u(z,t))\frac{\partial u}{\partial z},$$
where primes denote derivatives for the single-variable function $g$ with respect to its argument.